# Is it safe to hardcode a PPK file into my code?

Tags: c#, server, sftp

I created an app that stores and downloads data from a server (it's key-based authentication, not password btw). However, I want to make it things simpler for everyone by hardcoding the key file location. On one hand, it will save a bit of time for people using it, but on the other hand, I am concerned about the security, lest someone abuses the data in the server. If I share my app with a third party, is this practice safe, since anyone can access the server? It's not like I'm sharing the source code. I'm just sharing the program itself.

Code

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) //Browsing for Key File
        {
            OpenFileDialog keyOfd = new OpenFileDialog();
            keyOfd.Title = "Browse for Key File";
            keyOfd.Filter = "Key Files(*.pem;*.ppk)|*.pem;*.ppk";

            if (keyOfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = keyOfd.FileName;
                var privateKey = new PrivateKeyFile(textBox1.Text);
                populateData();
                using (var client = new SftpClient(Host, Port, Username, new[] { privateKey }))
                {
                    client.Connect();
                    const string workingdirectory = "/home/ubuntu/";
                    client.ChangeDirectory(workingdirectory);
                }

            }
        }

 void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var privateKey = new PrivateKeyFile(textBox1.Text);
                const string workingdirectory = "/home/ubuntu/";
                using (var client = new SftpClient(Host, Port, Username, new[] { privateKey }))
                {
                    client.Connect();
                    client.ChangeDirectory(workingdirectory);
                    string uploadFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "User Data\\") + "userData.csv";
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(uploadFile, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024; // bypass Payload error large files
                        client.UploadFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(uploadFile));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                ErrorWindow eWindow = new ErrorWindow();
                eWindow.label4.Text = err.GetType().ToString();
                eWindow.errorDetails.Text = err.Message;
                eWindow.ShowDialog();
            }
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: It will be trivial to extract the PPK from the compiled application. The safest approach is always to assume that if someone has access to your executable, they have access to anything contained within it, secret or not.

Comment: As @Llama has said, no it is not safe. A PPK is a putty private key. A private key should be specific to the machine that is accessing it. If you are redistributing an EXE that needs access to a PPK file you should generate a new one per machine.